# Creating a Table of Contents in Share Point Wiki Program

Tags: sharepoint-2010, wiki

Hey I am not sure this is a question for this site but I am making wiki pages in a share point for my job but I notice they all just accumulate with no table of contents. Im wondering is there a way to make a table of contents page that allows the user to see all of the wiki pages made and allows them to click on the link to the page.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

do you mean that you want to see all the pages? 
simply go to the all pages view, like this: http://sitename/LibraryName/Forms/AllPages.aspx